# Windows 7 folder creation error

Tags: windows-7

I get this message when I create a new folder anywhere on the drive. If I hit try again it makes the folder and no additional errors, has anyone seen this behavior before?

It only does it if I change the default name during creation, if I leave it "New folder" it makes it without error. Strange the message says "New folder" when I have named it something else. If I change any folder name it generates a similar message.

System is clean, regular scans both online and offline.

Restarted several times.

Windows 7 64bit Pro.

[image]

Comment: Have you run a disk check to ensure there's no file system corruption?

Comment: Yes, I do regular chkdsk's as part of my maintenance routine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into this issue on Windows 7 x64 as well.

- Install hotfix [**KB980408**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18532)
- Remove all of the following registry entries:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{2112AB0A-C86A-4ffe-A368-0DE96E47012E}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{491E922F-5643-4af4-A7EB-4E7A138D8174}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{7b0db17d-9cd2-4a93-9733-46cc89022e7c}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{A302545D-DEFF-464b-ABE8-61C8648D939B}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{A990AE9F-A03B-4e80-94BC-9912D7504104}]
```

- Reboot the system

Credits to HellGates of overclockers.net for [**this fix**](http://www.overclock.net/windows/721973-msupdate-kb980408-warning-all-win7-x64-2.html).

Comment: Thanks, downloaded the reg file and merged it, rebooted and the problem is gone! no need to install hotfix.

Comment: That was an old post on overclockers, seems a hotfix from 2010 caused the issue, not sure what caused mine since it stays up to date on patches and this was a recent problem.